# OkHttpClient with followRedirects(false) returns response with body=null

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using **retrofit** for http requests, when I start a post request, response is coming from another url and got 500 error code than I set **followRedirects** to false, for preventing redirection, but now I got response, where response body is null and **rawResponse** contains this message **code=302 message=Found**. I tried same request using Postman and works fine.

This is my retrofit interface Factory class

```
 class Factory {
    final static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
            .followSslRedirects(false);

    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    private static NetworkApi.Factory serverApi;
    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

    public static NetworkApi getApi() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return chain.proceed(builder.build());
                }
            });

            httpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor);
        }
        if (serverApi == null){
            serverApi = new NetworkApi.Factory();
        }
        return serverApi.retrofit.create(NetworkApi.class);
    }
}
```

retrofit library version is **2.1.0**

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? You told okhttp to not follow 302 redirects automatically so you get such redirect response returned back to you.

Comment: problem is that response body is null

Comment: Yes, redirects work that way - they use headers to point the http client to another location.

Comment: and what is your suggestions? how can I retrieve response body

Comment: Either allow okhttp to handle the redirect for you, or submit your request to the real destination URL in the first place.

Comment: If I allow redirection I have a response body=null, networkResponse with code=500,  and url is another and this returned url doesn't works for this request.
P.S. is returned URL real destination?

Comment: 500 is an error on the server side - possibly you're calling the api incorrectly and the service fails to work with your request.

Comment: nope, I'm sure request is correct :/  but thanks at all.

Comment: I second @laalto and you sure need to check that call that produces 500. Most likely postman sends some headers by default that retrofit doesn't and your server can't cope with the lack of them and just errors with 500.